# Excel Button Opening VBA Screen instead of Running the code

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in writing VBA code and adding macros to sheets. The code that i have written changes the value of a specific cell in the same sheet where the trigger button is. However, when i click the button, the vba window opens. The code runs and the value is changed but I do not understand why the vba window opens up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have debug mode on? Probably try removing all breakpoints.

VBA Editor -> Debug -> Clear All Breakpoints

Comment: that actually solved it. but what did that do? could you help me understand?

Comment: A Breakpoint pauses the execution of your could on a designated line. This is helpful when debugging your VBA code because it allows you to run parts of your code that are bug-free while pausing the execution of your macro in areas that need further testing.